# How can I redefine germanb.ldf-shorthand "| for italics only?

Tags: babel, ligatures, shorthands

`germanb.ldf` defines the very useful shorthand `"|` as

```
\declare@shorthand{german}{"|}{%
 \textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}%
         \allowhyphens}{}}
```

to be used by `\usepackage[german]` and `[ngerman]{babel}` or `\setxxxlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}`.

BTW: As a creature of habit I use the shorthand for other languages as well.

Now, the typographical demon says that you must not add *any* extra space in italics, so it shouldn't do more than to mark a preferred breaking point and maybe prevent ligatures like `ff` (FB00 ... FB04) -- if there are any in the italic font shape, but you may use the ligatures as well.

Is it possible to redefine one and the same shorthand in such a way that it behaves in a different way with different font shapes?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you have a more or less authoritative reference for the claim that "the typographical demon says that you must not add any extra space in italics" [while breaking up ligatures]? (FWIW, my view is that for breaking up ff and f-fl ligatures, it's *not* necessary to insert whitespace, in either upright or italic fontshapes; to break up fi ligatures, a minimalist amount of whitespace may be called for (but not as much as 0.03em, for sure); and to break up fl and ff-l ligatures, something like `0.03em` is about right -- in *both* upright and italic fontshapes.)

Comment: Shortly after its appearance the common demon tends to hide, but I'll try to evoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not convinced why you want to do this, but the standard test for an italic or sloping font is whether font dimension 1 is positive, so you can write:

```
\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand[german]{"|}{%
 \textormath{\penalty10000\discretionary{-}{}{\ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt\kern0pt\else\kern.03em\fi}%
 \allowhyphens}{}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=german]{babel}

\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand[german]{"|}{%
 \textormath{\penalty10000\discretionary{-}{}{\ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt\kern0pt\else\kern.03em\fi}%
 \allowhyphens}{}}

\begin{document}

f"|f ff \textit{f"|f ff} \textbf{f"|f ff} \textbf{\itshape f"|f ff}

Now some silly values to see this is working
\defineshorthand[german]{"|}{%
 \textormath{\penalty10000\discretionary{-}{}{\ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt\kern-2pt\else\kern.5em\fi}%
 \allowhyphens}{}}

f"|f ff \textit{f"|f ff} \textbf{f"|f ff} \textbf{\itshape f"|f ff}

\end{document}
```